# Assigning binary to src isn't calling binary function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image

The below code is what is happening behind code

```
Dim test1 As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("test1"), HtmlGenericControl)
        Dim image As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgFullImage"), HtmlGenericControl)
        hypImageProduct.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver",
                                       "ShowContent('" + test1.ClientID + "');document.getelementbyid('" + image.ClientID + "').src ='binary('" + Convert.ToBase64String(New DataClass().getProductStockPhoto(image.Attributes("alt"), 40, 40)) + "')';")
```

Then the following is the function that is used onpage for the binary but for some reason it seems that it isn't being called

```
function binary(d) {
        var o = '';
        for (var i=0; i<d.length; i=i+2) o+=String.fromCharCode(eval('0x'+(d.substring(i,i+2)).toString(16)));
        return o;
    }
```

I am probably doing something stupid and not noticing but i thought that it should work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra apostrophes around the function call. Change this:

```
... +"').src ='binary('" + ... + "')';")
```

into:

```
... +"').src = binary('" + ... + "');")
```